# How to make Object-C code in Xcode4 more structural and beautiful?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5, indentation

I know that Xcode provides the native "structure" functions to re-indent the code etc, but I still would like to question here to look for more powerful tool or way to structure my code better.

Any ideas or clues for me to achieve this goal ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) is a code prettifier. [Here](https://github.com/tonyarnold/Xcode-4-Uncrustify-Automator-Services) you'll find a tool to integrate it in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just beginning to learn Objective-C myself. My belief is that the most powerful tools for improving the structure of your code are experience and a consistent coding style.

You should check out Apple's coding guidelines for Cocoa programming. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html. Maybe take a look at a few different style guides and find a style you like, or download the source for an application that has been developed in Objective-C by more experienced programmers to see how they structure their code.

I don't know of any automated tools off the top of my head that will magically beautify your code (although I am sure they exist in some form), but I don't really think they're necessary. `Command+[` indents the selected lines one level to the left, and `Command+]` indents one level to the right. That's all I use.